# Lambda layers node_modules

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating a lambda layer, bundling up some dependencies, including node_modules. I am successfully creating a layer but when i try to require a module from my code, the console is telling me that the module cannot be found. Here is the code

```
var Promise = require('promise');
module.exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {   
  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(null, "helloWorld2");
    }, 9000);
  });
};
```

How can I reference node modules from a layer???

Comment: `promise` is not a module, it's ecma-script's feature. just remove `var Promise = require('promise');` other part of code is ok

Comment: It is a module you can npm install it. You can also install bluebird promise library as well among others.

Comment: strange that You've to install such package when You can just choose nodejs version from 8.x.x that already has promise feature

Comment: I have just tried to include another module and it still has the same error

Comment: What if i'm using an older version of node? I'm well aware that promises are built in to newer versions of node. please keep on topic

Comment: `the console is telling me that the module cannot be found.` can You show us that error? maybe it does not mean promise module cannot be found?

Comment: This slightly more recent question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842899/aws-lambda-layer-shared-library-in-node-modules-not-accesible-in-function - implies a permissions problem caused the same error. It also implies the zip needs a nodejs folder above the node_modules folder (though I’m not sure why). Do either of those help?

Comment: Oh - found some docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path - the nodejs folder is needed, if you don’t already have it.

Answer (score 9):

How are you running your lambda? If via [sam cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-reference.html), something like the below has worked for me as my `template.yaml` ...

#### example template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: example of node.js lambda function using layer for dependencies

Resources:

  ExampleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      CodeUri: nodejs/
      Handler: src/event.handler
      Layers:
        - !Ref NodeModulesLayer

  NodeModulesLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      Description: full set of function dependencies
      ContentUri: ./
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs6.10
        - nodejs8.10
      LicenseInfo: 'Available under the MIT-0 license.'
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

#### pointing to local layer

The SAM developer guide includes a page on [*Working with Layers*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-layers.html). At the time I'm writing this, they don't really get into how to reference layers at local file paths, and instead focus on references to remotely hosted layers.

The aspect I found tricky is that the directory structure of a node.js layer is expected to be ...

```
nodejs/
  node_modules/
```

... which means that in order for your locally installed `node_modules` directory to work as a layer, your `package.json` file must be nested inside a folder named `nodejs`.

Note the paths in the above example `template.yaml`:

1. `ExampleFunction.Properties.CodeUri` is set to `nodejs/`
2. `ExampleFunction.Properties.Handler` should be set to the path to your handler file, relative to `nodejs/`.
3. `NodeModulesLayer.Properties.ContentUri` is set to the folder that contains both the `template.yaml` file and the `nodejs` dir.

Which means my example is assuming the following structure ...

```
nodejs/
  node_modules/
  src/
    event.js
  package.json
template.yaml
```

#### preserve sam build support

One additional gotcha to be wary of ...

With respect to defining your function resource in `template.yaml`, there's some "flexibility" in terms of which parts of the path you put in `CodeUri` vs `Handler`. In some cases, doing ...

```
    Properties:
      CodeUri: nodejs/src/
      Handler: event.handler
```

... works just as well as doing ...

```
    Properties:
      CodeUri: nodejs/
      Handler: src/event.handler
```

BUT, if you're using the `sam build` command, the former will NOT work. That command expects to find `package.json` inside of the `CodeUri` directory. So, stick with `CodeUri: nodejs/` and use the `Handler` value to navigate through any additional folder hierarchy necessary to reaching your handler.

Comment: This works great when I build, but when I pack it using sam, it packs the node_modules twice. Once into my function code and the other into a layer. @RH Becker, do you have a suggestion on how to resolve this?

Comment: @NaphtaliGilead: I don't. My recent work hasn't involved sam. If, when I eventually get back to it, I come across any good approaches, I'll share. Please do the same, if you figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, simple example how to set up lambda layer in nodejs:

https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/nodejs-runtime-environment-with-aws-lambda-layers-f3914613e20e

Answer (score 1):

In order to address your module you have to use path with '/opt' as a prefix.

If it's yours file which you packaged to `myLib.zip` with `myLib.js` inside you should write:

```
const myModule = require('/opt/myLib');
```

If you plugging installed dependency then you upload `node_modules.zip` with `node_modules` folder and address as:

```
const module = require('/opt/node_modules/lib_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dependencies in 2022...

It was quite hard for me to figure out, whether this is still state-of-the-art or we can simplify dependencies now. **Turns out it's possible now to include dependencies without hacks or complicated setup.**

For me, creating the lambda with `new lambda.NodeJsFunction()` instead of `new lambda.Function()` [did the trick](https://github.com/AntoniusGolly/cdk-lambda-typescript-boilerplate/blob/master/lib/legacy-wrapper-stack.ts#L16). Yet, it was super hard for me to find a working sample. I decided to share a sample repo with you.

### Sample repository

https://github.com/AntoniusGolly/cdk-lambda-typescript-boilerplate

What it does:

- it has a lot of stuff you don't need to demonstrate the purpose (e.g. it produces a API Gateway based on a config.ts, so ignore that part if you don't need it)
- it allows you to use TS and ES6
- it allows you to use a dependency: i.e. I use node-fetch [here](https://github.com/AntoniusGolly/cdk-lambda-typescript-boilerplate/blob/master/src/handler.ts#L26)
- I just do `cdk deploy` and no other bundling
- [according to the docu](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#externals) by default, all node modules are bundled except for aws-sdk.
- I don't know exactly how it works, but it does ;)

I hope this helps someone as I would have appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way that i found is to run ls command on the run time

```
const fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const layerDirectory = '/opt'; // Replace with the actual path to the Layer directory

    try {
        const files = fs.readdirSync(layerDirectory);
        console.log('Contents of the Lambda Layer directory:');
        files.forEach((file) => {
            console.log(file);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error listing the directory:', error);
    }

    // Your Lambda function code here
};
```

the output

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: ff8d6039-78f5-46c8-a151-7a6da51404c9 Version: $LATEST
2023-10-11T16:49:56.045Z    ff8d6039-78f5-46c8-a151-7a6da51404c9    INFO    Contents of the Lambda Layer directory:
2023-10-11T16:49:56.045Z    ff8d6039-78f5-46c8-a151-7a6da51404c9    INFO    node_modules
2023-10-11T16:49:56.054Z    ff8d6039-78f5-46c8-a151-7a6da51404c9    INFO    package-lock.json
2023-10-11T16:49:56.054Z    ff8d6039-78f5-46c8-a151-7a6da51404c9    INFO    package.json
END RequestId: ff8d6039-78f5-46c8-a151-7a6da51404c9
REPORT RequestId: ff8d6039-78f5-46c8-a151-7a6da51404c9  Duration: 11.99 ms  Billed Duration: 12 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 67 MB  Init Duration: 163.70 ms
```

here you can see that the files deployed inside node_modules under /opt directly, so in my case here is the working import statement

```
const axios = require('/opt/node_modules/axios');
```