How to implement RxJS in AWS Lambda using the AWS Console
I would like to implement RxJS in my AWS Lambda in NodeJS via the AWS Console
But when I try to implement
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
It hits an error of "errorMessage": "Cannot find package 'rxjs' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"
How to rectify such issues, or how to import Observable or use any function in RxJS properly in my AWS Lambda function in NodeJS via the AWS Console

Are you using lambda layers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788753/lambda-layers-node-modules
